# Django admin default autocomplete filter not working

Tags: django, django-3.0

Django 2.* & Django 3. admin default autocomplete field not working with filter. Is there are any temporary fix until Django fixes this issue?

"purchasingorders" is a foreign key.if remove from autocomplete_fields its working fine. formfield_for_foreignkey function not working with autocomplete_fields

```
class GoodReceivedNoteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ['purchasingorders']
 
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
       if db_field.name == "purchasingorders":
          branch_code = request.session['branch']
          kwargs["queryset"] = PurchasingOrders.objects.filter(branch_code=branch_code)
          return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Thanks

Comment: *default autocomplete filter of Django*? Can you add some reference?

Comment: Code also updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with 'get_search_results'.

```
class PurchasingOrdersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, use_distinct = super().get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
        if 'autocomplete' in request.path:
            branch_code = request.session['branch']
            queryset = queryset.filter(branch_code=branch_code)
        return queryset, use_distinct
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with you, I am switching another library instead of using the default autocomplete filter fix my problem, here are the autocomplete light's library docs for your reference [django autocomplete light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#overview)

But I am preferring another solution based on the default autocomplete filter, the solution I propose just a temporary solution. Do update here, if had a better solution.